# Как сохранять файлы на русском языке KOI8-R с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

Файлы приходят вот в таком виде:

```
array ('#$A' ''filename'' => '#$A' array ('#$A' ''name'' => ''=?KOI8-R?B?4dfEz9TY0TIzMi50eHQ=?='','#$A' ''type'' => ''multipart/form-data'','#$A' ''tmp_name'' => ''C:\\wamp64\\tmp\\phpA593.tmp'','#$A' ''error'' => 0,'#$A' ''size'' => 6,'#$A' ),'#$A')
```

Пробовал использовать iconv, mb_convert_encoding для смены кодировки - не помогло.
Как можно полученную строку корректно декодировать например в UTF8?

P.S.
Можно сменить приходящую строку (например делать транслитерацию перед отправкой) нет возможности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, как интересует именно строка

> =?KOI8-R?B?4dfEz9TY0TIzMi50eHQ=?=

Формат по виду совпадает с описанным в [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) и его можно разобрать, например, функцией [`imap_mime_header_decode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php) из пакета `IMAP` вот таким способом:

```
function str_rfc2047_to_utf8($data) {
    $decoded_data = imap_mime_header_decode($data);
    if (empty($decoded_data) or !is_array($decoded_data)) {
        throw new \LogicException('unable decode input');
    }
    $item = current($decoded_data);
    if ($item->charset == 'default') {
        // ASCII text, compatible with UTF8, can return
        return $item->text;
    } else {
        // something else, try iconv
        return iconv($item->charset, 'utf8', $item->text);
    }
}

var_dump(str_rfc2047_to_utf8('=?KOI8-R?B?4dfEz9TY0TIzMi50eHQ=?='));
```

Откуда мы узнаем, что закодированный текст был `Авдотья232.txt` и, что отдельно приятно, без необходимости заранее знать кодировку исходного текста.

---

Если же вас интересует формат целиком как вы привели в вопросе - тут только писать вручную парсер. Несколько похоже на сломанный вывод `print_r`, попробуйте начать поиски с этого направления.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно!